Add Windows context menu option to run a .bat script, passing in directory as argument
I wrote a .bat script which takes in a network location (e.g. \\devserver) and open an RDP session to that server. I'd like to be able to run it via the File Explorer context menu.
I've added a registry key at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\directory\background\shell\Open RDP Session\command and set the default value to C:\scripts\StartRDP.bat "%1". The context menu option does appear, but nothing happens when I click it. Running the script manually works fine.


Is there something wrong with my registry entry?

You might try enclosing the file path in quotes, too, e.g., "C:\scripts\StartRDP.bat" "%1" Also try adding a pause in the script, to see what it is doing -- or if it even gets called.

No difference with the quotes. I've confirmed via logging that it's not even getting called.
